# How to resolve CORS headers problem on Netlify and Heroku

Tags: flutter, heroku, django-rest-framework, cors, netlify

Flutter Django app is hosted on Netlify and Heroku. When user tries to login the following error message is shown: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at [heroku url] from origin [netlify url] has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
In Django settings I have the following:

```
#settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # other apps
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    # other middlewares
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    [netlify url],
    [heroku url],

]
```

On netlify, I've done following added:
`_headers` and `.toml` and added _headers to build command:

```
Build Command: 
if [ -d "flutter" ]; then cd flutter && git pull && cd ..; else git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git; fi; flutter/bin/flutter build web; cp _headers build/web/

#_headers
/*
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

#netlify.toml
[[headers]]
  for = "/*"  # Match all paths
  [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"  # or specify your allowed domains here
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
    Access-Control-Allow-Methods = "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

I have heroku config vars with ALLOWED_HOSTS set to allow access to netlify. I'm not sure what else I can do to resolve this issue. Any ideas? Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% certain if this will solve your issue, but on one of my Netlify projects I have a file named _headers in the root directory with the following content:

```
/*
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Here is a link to the Netlify documentation that provides more detail:
https://docs.netlify.com/routing/headers/

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I added that but still no luck.